# Django: Duplicate Unique ID with UUID4 on race condition

Tags: python, mysql, django, uuid

I am using `uuid.uuid4().hex` to genrate random unique key which I want to use as a `key` for resetting the password.

There is a scenrio, where multiple users try to request the password change, I am expereincing `IntegrityError` as the `key` is getting duplicating.

I know its highly unlikly that `uuid.uuid4().hex` genrates a duplicate key, But in this scenrio, a race condtion on the request, they key is getting duplicated.

There are couple of ways which I have figgured out, but I wonder what is the better one.

### Try / Except

```
saved = false
while not saved:
    key = uuid.uuid4().hex
    try:
        reset_password_object.key = key
        reset_password_object.save()
        saved = True
    except IntegrityError:
       key = uuid.uuid4().hex
```

### Filter on Model

found = True

```
while found:
    key  = uuid.uuid4().hex
    found = ResetPassword.objects.filter(key=key).count()
```

Then use this key to add a new entry.

What can be the other possibilities? 
Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion, first approach is better, because, only when key is duplicated an extra database sentence is raised. Also, in second approach, in your scenario, it is better to use `exists` instead of `count`:  [The most efficient method of finding whether a model with a unique field (e.g. primary_key)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#exists). The last advice is that you should delete time by time obsolete table rows to avoid collisions. For me this is a comment but an answer. But let me know if this is a valid answer for you to post as solution.

Comment: You could try to add context specific information to your unique ID, something like database ID.

Comment: `def do_password_change_request(user, new_pswd,activation_key=None):`  Can using `activation_key` in the arguments cause duplications?

Answer (score 0):

If I was in your position I would have regenerated some 10K or 20K keys prior using it. Would have stored them in redis.

1. Create Unique UUID around 10K or 20K
2. Store them in redis key, and LPOP each time you need it.
3. When you have used all 10K or 20K UUID regenerate again, via cron or some mechanism.

This way your programme will be optimized.